# Why is it sac de jour and not sac du jour?

Tags: grammaire, articles, déterminants

Been thinking about this for awhile. There's a bag named *sac de jour*, but I have been wondering why it isn't called *sac du jour*.

Is there a difference between the meaning between two?

Answer (score 5):

Of course, there is ! Those are not the same word : specifically *du* is the contraction of *de le*.

In that specific case “*sac de jour*” means “day bag” as in a bag you would wear during the day and not in the evening (though it sounds a bit silly, then again : fashion), whereas a “*sac du jour*” would be a “bag of the day”, as in either the one of your many bags that you would wear specifically today, or a bag that has been made today (again, unlikely).

Comment: +1 I'd add *de jour* can also refer to casual dressing (as opposed to dressed up). And *sac du jour*, like "bag of the day" in English,  could  also refer to a "special offer",  a shop offers a rebate on a different bag bag every day (that can be submitted to as specific condition such as spending a minimum amount on other items...)